# Encrypt a string according to the table

Tags: arrays, c, encryption, multidimensional-array, cryptography

I have a problem. For example there is a table like this: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgpYF.png)

and want to enter a string for instance like `str[] = "şğüö 1234?!"` and the program will print the the code like `2422545376354555655666`.

It is a encryption question. I created a two dimensional array like this:

```
char signs[7][6] =     {{'A', 'G', 'L', 'S', 'Z', '6'},
                        {'B', 'Ğ', 'M', 'Ş', '0', '7'},
                        {'C', 'H', 'N', 'T', '1', '8'},
                        {'Ç', 'I', 'O', 'U', '2', '9'},
                        {'D', 'İ', 'Ö', 'Ü', '3', '?'},
                        {'E', 'J', 'P', 'V', '4', '!'},
                        {'F', 'K', 'R', 'Y', '5', ' '}};
```

And I thought that I could search the string's letters in this two-dimensional array. When the program find the letter, it can print the values of i and j. (Nested loops' elements)

Do you have another solution for that question? I really need your help. Because I cannot do that.

Comment: Two loops sounds like a good start. Why don't you try that?

Comment: @r3mainer Plain ASCII is only seven bits. "Extended" ASCII (or other common encodings like Windows-1252) is eight bits. Characters such as those could be part of the extended eight-bit encoding.

Comment: @r3mainer Furthermore, while `sizeof(char)` is specified to always be equal to `1`, there's no requirement it must be eight bits. There are platforms in somewhat common use today where it's 16 or even 32 bits (typically on signal processors).

Comment: I guess the input chars are 8-bit ISO/IEC 8859-9 (Turkish)?

Comment: One of your problems is shown between your table and your sample input. The table entries appear to be for UPPERCASE letters (and numbers) only. That is one more 'translation' hurdle to overcome...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using an 8bit "character code" table.

Rather than doing a "look-up" search through this table of yours, you could simply print the character translated to 2 hexadecimal values:

```
for( int i = 0; str[i]; i++ )
    printf( "%02X", (unsigned char)str[i] );
```

If you think that 'hex' would be too obvious, you could go for 3 digit octal instead:

```
    printf( "%03o", (unsigned char)str[i] );
```

There are myriad 'simple' encryption schemes that would defeat most casual observers.

Then, you must consider the 'decryption' complement to whatever scheme you choose.